# how to map an element in a list to a value from other list in LISP

Tags: lisp

I am new to lisp programming and i am trying to think about the below operation.

(extract '(0 1 0) '(a b c)) give us  '(a b a)

(extract  '(1 1 1 ) '(a b c)) gives us '(b b b)

how can i think about this and how to solve it.

Comment: Scott Hunter's answer describes what the function does correctly. If you wish to implement it, combine `mapcar` and `nth` (Common Lisp) or `map` and `list-ref` (Scheme) in some appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(extract a b)` returns a copy of `a` where each element is replaced by the element of `b` in that position.

Comment: its like a b c is indexed as 0 1 2 respectively, if the first list is 0 1 0 and the second list is m n o the out put of the function would be m n m. i would like to create a function that performs what i described above.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris Jester-Young described, it just returns elements from second list at indexes in first list. Writing such a function is very easy:

```
(defun extract (list-1 list-2)
  (mapcar (lambda (n) (nth n list-2)) list-1))

CL-USER>(extract '(0 1 0) '(a b c))
(A B A)
CL-USER>(extract '(1 1 1 ) '(a b c))
(B B B)
```

If there no such index, it'll give you `NIL` in that place.

```
CL-USER> (extract '(1 100 1 ) '(a b c))
(B NIL B)
```

But this won't work on nested structures (trees). If you want it to return elements of list-2 shaped in the structure of list-1, you can use a simple maptree helper function, then do the same thing:

```
(defun maptree (fn tree)
  (cond
    ((null tree) tree)
    ((atom tree) (funcall fn tree))
    (t (cons
     (maptree fn (first tree))
     (maptree fn (rest tree))))))


(defun extract* (list-1 list-2)
  (maptree (lambda (n)
             (nth n list-2)) list-1))

CL-USER> (extract* '(3 (2 1 (0))) '(a b c d)) 
(D (C B (A)))
```

Comment: i a quite confused of how lisp is working, i am used to java and this is pretty different.